# How to show all CPT posts in one page?

Tags: custom-post-types

How can I show all the CPT ( Custom Post Type ) posts in one single page? I can view a single CPT post using single-{CPT name}.php file but I am unable to use the archive-{CPT name}.php

I have a CPT as DProject and lets say I have one CPT post SPINNER

www.localhost.com/DProject/SPINNER is visible just like single post
but what I want is

www.localhost.com/DProject to show all the CPT posts in one single page just like default post using index.php and the loop.

Please Help.

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this if you think through how the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) works carefully enough.

- `archive-post.php` should handle your standard `post` post types
- `archive.php` would then handle the rest of the archives
- You may want specialized category-- `category.php`
- or tag archives-- `tag.php`

A similar pattern should work for single post display.

- `single-post.php` should handle your single `post` post type
- `single.php` should handle everything else